# Maps Activity in Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

I have a problem in showing the maps activity in navigation drawer. Here is my code.

MainActivity.java (This is my navigation drawer)

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private ListView mDrawerList;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private String mActivityTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

    addDrawerItems();
    setupDrawer();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}

private void addDrawerItems() {
    String[] Array = { "Driver Details", "Track Me", "Contact", "Report Driver", "Call For Emergency", "Rate Taxi", "Favorites", "Top Drivers", "Security Tips" };
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Array);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), DriverDetails.class));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MapsActivity.class));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Contact", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Report Driver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Call for Emergency", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Rate Taxi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Top Drivers", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 8:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Security Tips", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

private void setupDrawer() {
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("TaxiSafe");
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    // Activate the navigation drawer toggle
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

MapsActivity.java

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();


}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
}
}
```

activity_maps.xml

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="386dp"
    android:layout_height="573dp" android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context="com.example.group.taxisafe.MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--
   The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/taxisafe"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="TaxiSafe" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Register"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Home"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DriverDetails"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_driver_details" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

I am working fine in a separate project in creating the google map. When I put it to my project it always stopped every time I choose the track me in my navigation drawer. I don't know what is wrong with my code or what is lacking in my code.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! I realized what my problem is. Thank you!

Comment: You should write about the correct solution in the answer box provided so the question can be closed as solved. You can then click the "accept" answer tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend your Mapfragemnt as Fragemnt.. Not as FragmentActivity...

Then in your main activity, call the below code...

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, MapActivity());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

R.id.content_frame is the framelayout inside your MainActivity.xml...

I dont know what is the id you gave it to that framelayout since you didnt post the MainActivity.xml

Answer (score 1):

I just clean my project and build it again. then it is working when i run it again. i don't know what happen. :) Thank you for your comments. :)